# Find the probability that a randomly chosen student is studying?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Out of 150 Students, 70 are studying maths, 40 are studying physics and 15 are studying both math and physics. Find the probability that a randomly chosen student is studying :

A) math or physics 
B) neither math nor physics.

Comment: probability a randomly chosen student is studying *really* depends on time of the day, and day of the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Math OR physics = $P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B) - P(A \cap B) = \frac{110-15}{150}$

b)Neither math nor physics = 1 - "answer from part a"